# Accessing Input Text Box Value Inside a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html

In my code I am trying to acsess a input text box value while inside an external Javascript function.  However, I cannot seem to get the code to work. Could someone take a look at this code and determine what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED. IF ANYONE WANTS TO KNOW HOW TO ACSESS AN ELEMENT FROM A TEXT FIELD USING JAVASCRIPT FEEL FREE TO USE THIS AS A REFRENCE! Thanks.

Html Code:

```
  <body>

       <form action="VerifyRegistration.html" class="login">

           <h1>Sign Up Here</h1>


           /*Input Text Box*/
           <input type="email" input id = "email"  name="email" class="login-input" placeholder="Email Address" 


           <input type="submit" value="Create Account" class="createaccount">


          /*Once this button is pressed it calls a Javascript function
          <p class="login-help"><a href="javascript:FormChecker();">Need Help?</a></p>


          </form>

          </body>
          </html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
    <!--//

      function FormChecker(){
          Email = document.getElementById('email').value;
          alert(Email);
      }

    //-->
    </SCRIPT>
```

Note: These are in the same file and the javascript coe is below the html.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `getElementById('email')` but there is no element with ID "email"

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="login-input" placeholder="Email Address" autofocus>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was looking at the name and I confused this with the ID. Thanks!